# Magento 2 extension_attributes not update generate after comple

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Magento 2 extension_attributes not update generate after comple
Bellow is extension code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface">
        <attribute code="distance" type="string"/>
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

Bellow is genarated file:

```
<?php
namespace Magento\Quote\Api\Data;

/**
 * Extension class for @see \Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface
 */
class AddressExtension extends \Magento\Framework\Api\AbstractSimpleObject implements AddressExtensionInterface
{
    /**
     * @return \Magento\SalesRule\Api\Data\RuleDiscountInterface[]|null
     */
    public function getDiscounts()
    {
        return $this->_get('discounts');
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\SalesRule\Api\Data\RuleDiscountInterface[] $discounts
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setDiscounts($discounts)
    {
        $this->setData('discounts', $discounts);
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeInterface[]|null
     */
    public function getCheckoutFields()
    {
        return $this->_get('checkout_fields');
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Api\AttributeInterface[] $checkoutFields
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setCheckoutFields($checkoutFields)
    {
        $this->setData('checkout_fields', $checkoutFields);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

I remove generate file and also run di:compile But not working,
I use addressinterface:

```
<?php
namespace Danielozano\CustomerAttribute\Model;
use Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

class AddressInterface extends Template {

    /**
     * @var ShippingInformationInterface
     */
    private $_addressInformation;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_addressInformation = $addressInformation;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Get custom Shipping Charge
     *
     * @return String
     */
    public function getShippingCharge()
    {
        $extAttributes = $this->_addressInformation->getExtensionAttributes();
        return $extAttributes->getDistance(); //get custom attribute data.
    }
}
```

Log error on shipping:

```
[2020-03-08 02:41:07] main.CRITICAL: Report ID: webapi-5e645b43bf0dc; Message: Property "Distance" does not have accessor method "getDistance" in class "Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressExtensionInterface". {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Report ID: webapi-5e645b43bf0dc; Message: Property \"Distance\" does not have accessor method \"getDistance\" in class \"Magento\\Quote\\Api\\Data\\AddressExtensionInterface\". at /home/scyllat6/public_html/sla/m2/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:208, LogicException(code: 0): Property \"Distance\" does not have accessor method \"getDistance\" in class \"Magento\\Quote\\Api\\Data\\AddressExtensionInterface\". at /home/scyllat6/public_html/sla/m2/vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/NameFinder.php:100)"} []
```

I try to create a address attribute in Magneto 2.3.4 CE From Bellow link
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout_new_field.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking at the wrong generated file. Your generated file should be `generated/code/Magento/Customer/Api/Data/AddressExtension`.

Also the way you are retrieving extension attributes is not correct. You need to use the proper interface that was used for storing extension attributes. Here you are using `Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface` Interface to get value while you stored the value in `Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface`.